# @SectionedFetchRequest Type of expression is ambiguous

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, nsfetchrequest

I cant compile because of an error on my SectionedFetchRequest.  Gives the error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

```
struct FlightListView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Flight.trip?.date, ascending: true)],
    animation: .default)
private var flights: FetchedResults<Flight>

@SectionedFetchRequest<String, Flight>(
    sectionIdentifier: \.trip?.sortDate as? String,
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Flight.trip?.date, ascending: true)],
    predicate: nil,
    animation: .default)
private var groupedFlights: SectionedFetchRequest<String, Flight>
```

The regular fetch request compiles and is fine.  I cant figure out whats incorrect with my code.

Comment: Are you sure you can use optionals in the declaration? And why do you need to type cast a property, that looks a bit weird.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would really help to see a screenshot of your `Entity` in the `xcdatamodeld`.